How to get multiple data from dynamic form by FLASK / HTML?
I work on python web app.
In a page i want users to chose their friends to add their organization. But to build that page i prepare data in flask side first. Then i send it to HTML. Then i use for loop in HTML doc to build div blocks ( and add friend information into the blcok ). Then when user chose more than 1 friend, i want to get back data from the form to flask side to use data in my database. But unfortunatelly i cant receive all the values from checkboxes. Coz checkboxes are builded by for loop and all of them names are same.
Here is the flask side that i prepare the data. arkadasList goes to yeni.HTML.
@app.route("/yeni")
def newPlan():
    username = session["username"]
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    sorgu = "Select friends from users where username = %s"
    result = cursor.execute(sorgu,(username,))
    if result > 0:
        kanka = True
        arkadaslar = cursor.fetchone()
        arkadasList = list()
        arkadaslar = arkadaslar["friends"].split(",")
        arkadaslar.pop()
        for i in arkadaslar:
            sorgu2 = "Select name from users where username = %s"    
            cursor.execute(sorgu2,(i,))
            isim = cursor.fetchone()
            isim = isim["name"]
            kAdı = i
            x = dict(name=isim,username = kAdı)
            arkadasList.append(x)
    else:
        arkadasList = list()
        kanka = False
    return render_template("yeni.html",arkadasList=arkadasList, kanka=kanka)

Here in yeni.HTML doc i use for loop in arkadasList and build a div contains username and name for each loop. ( Also this codes covered by form as well. I did not add here to not make code longer )

<div class="arkadasEkle">
        <div class="arkadasBaslık">
          <h2>Ekleyebileceğiniz Arkadaşlarınız</h2>
          <p>Hesaba eklemek istediğiniz arkadaşlarınızı listeden seçiniz</p>
        </div>
        {% if kanka %} {% for ark in arkadasList %}
        <div class="arkadasKutu">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-user" style="font-size: 3.7rem"></i>
          <section>
            <label for="checkbox">{{ark.name}}</label>
            <label for="checkbox" style="font-size: 1.7rem"
              >{{ark.username}}</label
            >
          </section>

          <input
            type="checkbox"
            class="checkbox-round"
            value="{{ark.username}}"
            name="checkbox"
          />
        </div>
        {% endfor %} {% else %}
        <p>oradayım</p>
        {% endif %}
      </div>


Here i try to get data back from the FORM. But next pictures you will see, it only gives me the one that i clicked ( checkboxed ) first.
@app.route("/layout", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def layout():
    if request.method == "POST":
        x = request.form["paymentType"]
        a = request.form["hesapName"]
        c = request.form["hesapKat"]
        y = request.form["checkbox"]
        b = x+a+c+"----"+y
        return render_template("layout.html", b=b)
    else:

         return render_template("layout.html")

yeni.HTML
layout.HTML after post request from yeni.html
I want to receive the usernames that checkboxed

Have you tried using request.form.getlist('checkbox') since all input fields have the same name attribute and you want to request multiple values.
